# Bootstrap Collapse does not work if i change the ids on load with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml, bootstrap-4, odoo

So I'm trying to do a collapse info from each row of a table. The rows are generated from the Odoo framework, so, in order to associate the data-target to the corresponding ID, I iterated the table and changed the values of each.

Dispite the ids on the console and ,after inspecting the element being the same, the collapse does not work.

Can you guys help me to find the reason and a possible solution? Thanks in advance.

Javascript

```
var table = document.getElementById("social_programs_table");
    var incr = 0;

    //i = 1, because the first row should be ignored
    for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
        //iterate through rows

        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            incr++;
            row.cells[5].firstChild.nextElementSibling.dataset.target = "target" + incr;
            console.log("Row Target ID: " + row.cells[5].firstChild.nextElementSibling.dataset.target);
        }
        else {
            row.id = "target" + incr;
            console.log("Row ID: " + row.id);
        }
}
```

Respective Table

```
 <table class="table table-striped" id="social_programs_table">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th scope="col">Nome da Entidade</th>
                                <th scope="col">Designação do Projeto</th>
                                <th scope="col">Duração (meses)</th>
                                <th scope="col">População-alvo</th>
                                <th scope="col">Fonte de Financiamento</th>
                                <th scope="col">Saber Mais</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <!-- ? Loop -->
                                <t t-foreach="programs" t-as="obj">
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row"><t t-esc="obj.beneficiary_entity" /></th>
                                <td><t t-esc="obj.name" /></td>
                                <td><t t-esc="obj.duration" /></td>
                                <td><t t-esc="obj.target_audience" /></td>
                                <td><t t-esc="obj.financial_source" /></td>
                                <td id="collapse_td">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#target" id="collapse_btn">+</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                            <tr class="collapse out" id="target">
                                <td>This txt should be collapsed</td>
                            </tr>
                            </t>
                              <!-- ? End loop -->
                          </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason it's not working could be **duplicate ids**.

Try using any other unique value as id, like **t-att-id="obj.name"** & similarly assign the data-target as **t-att-data-target="obj.name"** and **use name only if it's unique** and here's code for your reference.

HTML CODE:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm ">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>Column</th>
            <th>Column</th>
            <th>Column</th>
            <th>Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#group-of-rows-1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="group-of-rows-1">
            <td><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="group-of-rows-1" class="collapse">
        <tr class="table-warning">
            <td><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> child row</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-warning">
            <td><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> child row</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
            <td>data 1</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="clickable" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#group-of-rows-2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="group-of-rows-2">
            <td><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody id="group-of-rows-2" class="collapse">
        <tr class="table-warning">
            <td><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> child row</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="table-warning">
            <td><i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> child row</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
            <td>data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But each collapsible tr is getting it's unique id, that's what that 'incr' variable is for. As you can see here: https://imgur.com/a/JbXmSau , there are no duplicate ids